# Task with graph - looking for advice

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I've a task with graph. I'm not looking for code, but only for idea. I don't know even where should I start..  so content of this task is:

in first line we have two number, n and q.

n - number of cities and q - number of days.

next line contain n integer number n1, n2, n3, n4...n_n where n_i means that we can earn n_i money in city with number i.

next n-1 lines desribe connection between city a and b.
each line is form a, b, c which is mean that

a is connected with b (and b with a) and cost of this path is c.

next we have q lines which desribe changes, we have 2 case

in form 1 v d which means that from dawn day i profit from city v will be d

and form 2 a b d which means that from dawn day i cost of path between a and b (and b to a) will be d

our task is print ids of city where we will be sleep after i day.

we start from city which index 1 and when we're in city number 2 then we will sleep in this city.

for example

input:

```
4 4
10 20 30 50
1 2 5
2 3 7
2 4 57
1 3 28
1 1 25
2 3 2 1
2 2 4 13
```

output:

```
3 1 3 4
```

sorry for my english :/ as I said before I'm not looking for code but for general idea.

@EDIT
maybe it will be some useful info. When we go to city with index B. We spend there night. Question is. Where we will be spend our nights. I mean how our path looks

Comment: What are the constraints for `n` and `q`? How big can they be?

Comment: both of them 100 000

Comment: so...question is? what is the maximum money I can earn?

Comment: maybe it will be some useful info. When we go to city with index B. We spend there night. Question is. Where we will be spend our nights. I mean how our path looks

Comment: it is clear or not now?

Comment: @Shihab Shahriar basically your question was correct, but in this task I don't to calculate maximum money but path to get this maximum money

Comment: I think you should add that in q